¿como se muestra la segunda pagina?
una duda como hago para que se me muestre la información cuando uno hace compaginación en la segunda pagina de una tabla que no se como hacerlo y estoy peleando
<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">ciudad</th>
            <th scope="col">pais</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($users as $index => $user)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ $index + 1 }}</th>
                <td>{{ $user->name}}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->city->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->city->country->name }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{$users->links()}}
</div>

este es una parte del codigo que estoy mostrando en pantalla
    public function render()
    {
        $users = User::paginate(5);
        return view('livewire.counter', ['users' => $users]);
    }

haci tengo la paginación
Espero me puedan ayudar
